# Book with a title reminiscent of "The Last Mimsy"

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I recently discovered that *The Last Mimzy* is not, in fact, the adaptation of a similarly titled book that I vaguely remember from childhood. So what was that book?

I think it was titled either "The Last [blank]" or possibly "The Great [blank]", where [blank] was a made-up word reminiscent of Mimsy.

I read it in 1993 or '94 (third grade). It was published before then (i.e. it wasn't a new release that year). It was written for a slightly older audience, but not much older. I used to think it was written by Roald Dahl, but it isn't anything listed as his. I remember thinking that it was similar to E. Nesbit's books, but it isn't hers either, and I don't remember *her* books well enough anymore to be confident in that.

The plot, as near as I can remember, was that two (or more?) children were taught by an older woman (a tutor or governess, maybe) about this [blank], who was some sort of sentient creature that was the last of his kind. Then they learned some sort of skill (I think some unspecified advanced mathematics, but it might also have been dream-based?) which allowed them to teleport to the see the [blank]. I recall the [blank] was small, and I think it was some sort of leader in whatever region it lived in. It taught them more of the same skill, and the youngest child advanced much faster than the POV character. I think the POV character (she?) eventually caught up, much to the younger brother(?)'s delight. I think they eventually decided they preferred to go home, and had to escape the dreamland/alternate reality/whatever.

I think this book may have used the word "tesseract," but I also read the Time Quartet the same year, so I may have blurred that together.

The book was a full novel. I remember it being larger than a trade paperback and something like 3/4 inch thick (no idea on page length or word count).

Any thoughts?

Comment: FWIW, you may already be aware, but *The Last Mimzy* is a loose adaptation of "Mimsy were the Borogroves" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimsy_Were_the_Borogoves)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I've read it, but not for a while. IIRC though, that was a fairly short story, and the book I'm thinking of was a full novel. On which note...

Comment: Could it be [*The Last T'En*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1961322.The_Last_T_En) by Rowena Cory Daniells?

Comment: @user14111 No. It was set starting in either the real world or something similar enough not to stand out. That's an impressively close match for the clues I remember though!

Comment: Here's a chronological list of speculative fiction novels titled [*The Last _____*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_ttype&OPERATOR_1=exact&TERM_1=NOVEL&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_title&OPERATOR_2=contains&TERM_2=the+last+&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_title&OPERATOR_3=notcontains&TERM_3=*+*+*+*&ORDERBY=title_copyright&START=0&TYPE=Title)) . . ..

Comment: . . . and here''s one for [*The Great* _____](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_ttype&OPERATOR_1=exact&TERM_1=NOVEL&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_title&OPERATOR_2=contains&TERM_2=the+great+*&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_title&OPERATOR_3=notcontains&TERM_3=*+*+*+*&ORDERBY=title_copyright&START=0&TYPE=Title).

Comment: If the [blank] was the last of its kind, who was it leading?

Comment: @user14111 I can't find anything that looks right under either list.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't know. I remember the sense that it had some sort of power or authority, but it may have just been because it was the children's host.

Comment: @Frock that sounds very likely. I'll have to find a copy, but the wikipedia description matches well.

Comment: @Frock why not put that as an answer?

Comment: It was indeed The Last of the Really Great Whangdoodles. As soon as I got to the part about "no-one ever looks up," it clicked. I'll wait a week or so in case @Frock wants to add it as an answer, but eventually someone should document it for the proper Q&A format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Last of the Really Great Whangdoodles** by Julie Edwards (Julie Andrews). 1974.

Three siblings, Ben, Tom, and Melinda Potter, meet Professor Savant while visiting the zoo one rainy day. After a second meeting, they begin spending time at the Professor's house, where he introduces them to games of concentration and observation. He reveals that there is a magic land called Whangdoodleland that can only be reached through the imagination, and that he is training them to accompany him there.